# For loop multiply in some range

Tags: python-3.x

I have a task for my college in which I must program some very simple logic for multiplying numbers in range like 1 to 5 and than multiply like 1*2*3*4*5. And this way for any input number. For 7 it would be 1*2*3*4*5*6*7. 
This is my modest code which is not finished because of no idea how to do it .Help, please..

```
number = int(input("Enter a number:"))
number += 1
for i in range(1,number):
    a = i*(number*
print(a)
```

Comment: This looks like something easily solved by looking in your text book or whatever course material you have.

Comment: I have a book, but no way to solve this in it. I solved 26 task before this one, but this is like some heavier task..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [1774]: number = int(input("Enter a number:"))
In [1775]: a = 1

In [1776]: for i in range(1, number+1):
      ...:     a *= i

In [1781]: a
Out[1781]: 120
```

`a`'s value is 120  which is basically (`1*2*3*4*5`). Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this is it. Its drive me crazy when I know it must be easy and dont have solution..thanks